# ConnectionFactoryCustomizer don't work with multiple rabbit binder

Tags: java, kotlin, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I want to create two rabbit binder, both use autintefication with TLS.

```
  @Bean
    fun connectionFactoryCustomizer(rabbitProperties: RabbitProperties): ConnectionFactoryCustomizer {
        return if (rabbitProperties.ssl.enabled == true) {
            ConnectionFactoryCustomizer { connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory ->
                connectionFactory.saslConfig = EXTERNAL
            }
        } else {
            ConnectionFactoryCustomizer { connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory ->
                connectionFactory.saslConfig = PLAIN
            }
        }
    }
```

application.yml

```
rabbitmq:
    ssl:
      enabled: true
cloud:
    stream:
      binders:
        rabbit1:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: localhost
                port: 5671
                virtual-host: /
                ssl:
                  enabled: true
                  algorithm: algorithm
                  verify-hostname: true
                  key-store: file:/rabbit
                  key-store-password: keystorepassword
                  trust-store: file:/rabbit
                  trust-store-password: truststorepassword
        rabbit2:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: localhost
                port: 5672
                virtual-host: /
                ssl:
                  enabled: true
                  algorithm: algorithm
                  verify-hostname: true
                  key-store: file:/rabbit
                  key-store-password: keystorepassword
                  trust-store: file:/rabbit
                  trust-store-password: truststorepassword
```

But I'm getting the error "Login was refused using authentification mechanism PLAIN.". How to set up multiplier binding with TLS?

Comment: What version of s-c-stream you are using?

Comment: spring-cloud-dependencies 2021.0.1

Comment: It's an issue that I am addressing as we speak - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2522. I will also attempt to back-port  it to 3.2.x

Comment: So the issue has been addressed and you can try it with 3.2.6-SNAPSHOT or 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT. We'll be releasing 3.2.6 (2021.0.5 of spring-cloud) at the end of the month